# Two-dimensional Kolmogorov–Smirnov

Tags: multivariate-analysis, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I would like to run some two dimensional Kolmogorov–Smironov tests to determine whether a two-dimensional distribution fits with a reference.

Is there any package or application that I could use in a relatively straightforward fashion? Or is there a different algorithm that is preferrable? I have just a basic statistical knowledge.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but I think the [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) applies to one-dimensional distributions. If you are interested on one of the proposal extensions (there are several because there is no natural extension to the multivariate case), please specify which one.

Comment: I'd rather say there is a natural extension to the multivariate case, but it involves the distribution of $\sup |K(t)|$ where $K$ is the Kiefer process (two-dimensional Brownian bridge), and this distribution is badly known.

Answer (score 13):

### Python implementation

I have written a python implementation using numpy. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/syrte/ndtest), you may find more infomation in the docstring in the code.

And here's another one (not by me). [This Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/cs.marlboro.edu/courses/spring2014/jims_tutorials/ahernandez/Apr_25.attachments/scic_stat_tests.ipynb#Two-Dimensional-K-S) provide a Python implementation for 2D K-S test with 2 samples. The `.py` file can be downloaded [here](http://cs.marlboro.edu/courses/spring2014/jims_tutorials/ahernandez/Apr_25.attachments). The code seems to be a straight translation of `C` code, the efficiency might be a problem if sample size is large.

However you'd better check the codes (no matter which one) with the original papers/books before you use. The python implementations of 2d KS test are far less checked than the ones in R.

### More infomation

The algorithm is first developed in two papers (as I see)

- [Peacock, J.A. 1983, Two-Dimensional Goodness-of-Fit Testing in Astronomy](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1983MNRAS.202..615P)
- [Fasano, G. and Franceschini, A. 1987, A Multidimensional Version of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1987MNRAS.225..155F).

A nice introduction and the `C` implementation can be found in

- [Press, W.H. et al. 1992, Numerical Recipes in C](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html), Section 14.7, p645.

  You can find `C++/Fortran` implementation in other versions of the book.

Here's a post titled [Beware the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://asaip.psu.edu/Articles/beware-the-kolmogorov-smirnov-test) is also related to the subject, you may want to have a look. It encourages using resample method to evaluate the p-value with given KS distance.

Answer (score 11):

A two-dimensional extension of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test has been described by Justel, Pena and Zamar in a ["A multivariate Komogorov-Smirnov test of goodness of fit"](http://halweb.uc3m.es/esp/Personal/personas/dpena/articles/kolpl97.pdf).  @Procrastinator's comments suggests there may be other such proposals.

However, I haven't seen a package with a straightforward implementation.

Depending on what you want to do, kde.test() in Tarn Duong's ks package for R might be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

you may find this Matlab code to be useful.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38617-two-dimensional-2d-paired-kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Comment: Welcome to this site! Could you provide a brief description of the resources available on that page?