# Significance for difference of points on an (x,y) grid

Tags: statistical-significance, kernel-smoothing, scatterplot

I have a set of data consisting of (x,y) points, divided among 4 groups.  What technique is most appropriate for deciding whether groups are significantly different? It's probably OK to use the simplest set of assumptions, except that the points between the groups aren't paired.  Here's an image showing a simplified example of what the points could look like.  [image]

This is probably a very basic question, but I don't know what to search under ...

Comment: Welcome to our site!  I have retagged this post on the understanding that the coordinates in your plots represent ordered pairs of outcomes in an experiment.  If that's not correct, then perhaps a little more explanation of what those coordinates do mean would help.

Comment: Without going into tedious detail, each point represents a physical grid location, where the treatment is expected to alter the final location of each subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're testing to see if the bivariate distribution $X,Y$ is different among groups A and B in plots 1 and 2. The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is a non-parametric test designed to assess the evidence against the assumption that two univariate distributions are identical. There is an article discussing a multivariate Kolmogorov-Smirnov test: www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/ajustel/papers/1997-spl.pdf

This is a bit more academic than you may be looking for. There are also links on the Wikipedia page for Kolmogorov-Smirnov that could be of help/interest to you!

Comment: Thanks! Searching for "multivariate Kolmogorov-Smirnov" led me to [this question here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27288/two-dimensional-kolmogorov-smirnov) where one answer suggested as an alternative the kde.test() function in the R ks package.  Does that seem like a reasonable solution?

Comment: Yes, this looks like it will work in up to six dimensions!